# How to remove white space between details sections which contain subreports in Crystal Reports

Tags: crystal-reports, sections

In my main report preview and exported PDF file of it as well I have a unused white space between details sections (the section with the grid starts from next page) as shown in the following image. Off course I want that white space to be removed.

[image]

I tried with unchecking the "Can Grow" and "Keep Together" in the sections which contains grid subreport (as well as in the subreport itself), but unfortunately I have no result. In case when I have for example 3 rows in the grid section, the section starts right under the chart section above, but in case when it must go to the next page, it makes that white space.

And to mention this, in both subreports in their sections, I have suppressed all the unnecessary sections, basically I am showing only the ones with the data.

Thanks.

Comment: I guess white can't be removed this case... as you are using sub report when data is more and doesn't fit in available space data is automatically moving to next page leaving white space. one option is try using `underlay following sections` for the white space section

Comment: Your link to the screenshot is broken. It's hard to visualize what you're talking about without it.

Comment: @Siva Thanks the reply, but it didn't help.

Comment: @Ryan I don't know what to say, I uploaded the image, I didn't use it from some URL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved this. I checked "Can Grow", and deselect the Keep Object together in the subreport.
And now the grid works fine! Starts at the end on the graph, and continues on to the next page. Here is what I done:

[image]